# Where does tracrRNA comes from?

Tags: molecular-biology, rna, crispr, noncoding-rna

I'm talking about CRISPR system. I know the crRNA is transcribed from the palindromic repeat and the "spacer" but I don't know where the tracrRNA comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the tracrRNA is a part of the CRISPR locus and is encoded in the the vicinity of the CRISPR array (e.g. upstream or downstream of the cas genes or the array).

http://www.genome-engineering.org/crispr/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/crispr_processing1.jpg